# How to export Embedded Power BI report to PPT and PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a scenario to export embedded power BI report into PPT and PDF formats in Asp.net MVC application. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to) mentions that the feature is still in preview as of today. How ever the  Power BI Rest APIs documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group) doesn't mention anything on that.

I'm not allowed to use preview features. Is this feature generally available? or it is still in preview?

If the feature is in preview, what are the other ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Export to file API general availability is planned for this month (September 2021), so it should reach general availability in few days. See [What's new and planned for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2021wave1/power-bi/planned-features):

[image]

Comment: I'm little confused here. Is the exportToFile in embedding scenarios in preview or the Power BI Rest API mentioned here at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group is in preview?

Comment: The Export to file API is is preview.